# SQL insert data taking more time

Tags: asp.net, sql, .net

In our ASP application we insert some data from customer to our database which is in a webserver.From a customer only one row is inserted at a time. Below is the structure of the table and all column are filled. While inserting the data from application it becomes slow as the table has large number of column.The column `Report` alone will be having text of about 20000 to 30000 characters. So I think it may be causing slow insertion of data to table and it may cause performance degradation for my web server. So what is the best method to insert the data to table of below kind. Now we just use normal SQL insert command and insert the row. Is there any better method to make insert statement faster and efficient for large content of data?

```
CREATE TABLE [Customer](    
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(2310,1) NOT NULL,
    [slno] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [onDate] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [onTime] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ip] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [custName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [custAddr] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [custCity] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [custPIN] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [custEmail] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [custTele] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [contactPer] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [batch] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Report] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PC] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [oldkey] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Office] [bit] NULL,
    [frameWorkVersion] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [keys] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [OSversion] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Res] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Version2] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Version1] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [EXEVersion] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [processorSpeed] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [RAM] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [SYSTEM] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [SYSTEMNAME] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [HOSTNAME] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [PCUSER] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [FeatureCount] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [IsRegistered] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Info1] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [OtherInfo] [varchar](8000) NULL,
    [WorkGroup] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [CustMainPhone] [varchar](255) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_downloadexe_errlog] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED   
(   
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]   
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: There are at least a few steps here: posting the page, uploading the form contents to the server, processing the page in ASP, sending data to the database, processing the SQL.  How long does each step take?

Comment: How are you performing your inserts?

Comment: Is it slow from the start or is it getting slow the more data you add to the table?

Comment: @JeffHornby Hey i am not inserting more number of rows. The insert will be only one row. From my every customer a single row will be inserted to database through ASP apps.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at table direct mode
http://blog.ropardo.ro/2011/05/17/parametrized-queries-vs-table-direct-mode-sql-server-ce/

or even better, use bulk insert
http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/03/01/effective-use-of-sql-bulk-insert.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any other indexes you are not showing?

With the much data it is probably just a volume thing.
You can insert multiple rows in one statement

```
values (), ()
```

Too many rows at a time then it can slow down
Keep the row * columns under 1000
So try like 20 rows at a time

Comment: Hey i am not inserting more number of rows. The insert will be only one row. From my every customer  a single row will be inserted to database through ASP apps.

Answer (score 0):

If there are indexes on the table follow the pattern below :

- Drop Index
- Insert data
- Re-Create Index

Comment: @Blam Hey i am not inserting more number of rows. The insert will be only one row for each customer. From my every customer a single row will be inserted to database through ASP apps and sql database is in web server.

Answer (score -1):

Try to make some

```
commit;
```

while you are inserting your rows, like every 20 or 50 rows.